# Accessing key/value pair in ArrayList<LinkedHashMap>

Tags: java, hash, arraylist, dictionary, intellij-idea

```
Object Value
```

[image]

Above is the evaluate expression in Intellij of an Object field. I want to access both key and value but unable to do so.

Comment: have you tried anything? any code?

Comment: What have you tried? Did you check out the [List API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html)?

Comment: I tried to get the first element of the ArrayList and then create an entry set of the map but it didn't work.

Comment: _It didn't work_ tells us close to nothing. Where is your code? What exceptions are you getting, if any?

Comment: result.get(0).entrySet() no?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to [iterate](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html) over your list, here is an example

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    List<LinkedHashMap<String,String>> list = new ArrayList<LinkedHashMap<String, String>>();

    LinkedHashMap<String, String> test = new LinkedHashMap<String, String>();
        test.put("a","1");
        test.put("b","2");

    list.add(test);

    for(Map<String, String> map : list){
        for(String key : map.keySet()){
            System.out.println("key: " + key + " value " + map.get(key));
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Had to cast `field` to ArrayList<LinkedHashMap>. Thanks!